# jquery attribute + index (in groups)

Tags: jquery, attributes, lightbox

I have six `<div class="gallery-popup">` elements. Inside each there are thumbnails inside `<a href="...">` tags. What I want, is to add attribute `data-lightbox="gallery-X"`, to each `<a>` element, but specific for each one of those 6 galleries. For example `gallery-1` for each `<a>` inside first `.gallery-popup`, `gallery-2` inside second and so on. Code which i have now is :

```
var thumbnailInterval = setInterval(function () {
    if ($('.offer .box_info_potos div .gallery-popup li a').length) {
        console.log('found' + $('.offer ').length);
        clearInterval(thumbnailInterval);

        $('.offer .gallery-popup a').each(function (index) {
            var a = $(this).get()[0];
            a.setAttribute('data-lightbox', 'gall-' + index);
            console.log(a);
        });
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: Why would you need to do this 10 times a second?

Comment: @charlietfl HTML is loaded by ajax from external source, which can't be changed. New attribute have to be "injected" inside. This method above works, but not as i want. Pic with explanaiton: [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/sl88yhgyd71kwx9/jquery-index.jpg?dl=0

Comment: So do this in an ajax callback. Index the groups not the `<a>`. Show expected results.

Comment: @charlietfl Regarding project limitations this have to be done in js/jquery.

Comment: ajax is done with js/jquery. Provide a [mcve]

Comment: @charlietfl yes, but i don't know how to use it. I'm not so advance yet with js/jquery. I can't send more than i have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.offer .gallery-popup').each(function (index,item) {
    $(item).find('a').attr('data-lightbox','gall-'+(index+1));
});
```

[See working example](https://jsfiddle.net/bzsjqsps/1/)

**Update**

See this image my code doing this.

[image]

Comment: doesn't work. Those html elements are loaded by ajax from external database and I need to "inject" those attributes. My code was working, but not as i wanted. My code add attribute from first to last element... (gal-1, gal-2) (gal-3, gal-4) and so on. What i want is (gal-1, gal-1)(gal-2, gal-2) - brackets here means groups (.gallery-popup).

Comment: here is link to picture with explanaitions:
[link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/sl88yhgyd71kwx9/jquery-index.jpg?dl=0

Comment: My example is doing same as you wanted see image in my updated answer @Jakub

Comment: Works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
 $('.offer .gallery-popup ').find('a').each(function (index,div) {
        div.setAttribute('data-lightbox', 'gall-' + index);
    });
```